# Populate List<Callable<String>> in Groovy with Groovy objects

Tags: groovy, embed

In [What JVM-based scripting language support @WebService to create services at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12034538/what-jvm-based-scripting-language-support-webservice-to-create-services-at-runt) I was suggested to use Groovy to provide web services configured in a script read in at runtime.

To make this work with our existing infrastructure I need essentially to be able to add new entries to a `List<Callable<String>>` which I then can ask an executor to invokeAny upon.

The basic structure will be something like:

- Groovy is embedded using `GroovyScriptEngine`
- Initial list passed in from Java as "l" in the Binding passed in.
- Groovy script defines and instantiates N objects, all implementing `Callable<String>` and add them to the list.
- Back in Java the list is then further processed and then passed to the executor.

My initial feeble steps show that I will most likely need to use `def c = { ... } as Callable<String>` but then I get a ClassCastException.  Reading up I see that it appears that this is a bit hard and involves closures.

What is the correct way to define and instantiate an object in Groovy which implements `Callable<String>`?

Comment: What version of Groovy are you using? Closure already implements Callable in Groovy 1.8 and later.

Comment: @IanRoberts  I pulled in groovy-all-1.0-jsr-05 from Maven which appeared to be the newest.  `org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.getVersion()` reports "1.0-jsr-05".  SHould I be using something else?

Comment: That's pretty ancient TBH.  [`org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.0.2`](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.codehaus.groovy%7Cgroovy-all%7C2.0.2%7Cjar) is the latest.

Comment: I updated and now the script works.  Could you please post an answer I can accept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Groovy 1.8 and later, `groovy.lang.Closure` implements `Callable` by default so you don't need any "as" magic., simply:

```
l << { "hello" }
l << { "world" }
```

For earlier versions of Groovy (1.6 and 1.7 certainly, not sure about "ancient" versions) you need to use `as`:

```
import java.util.concurrent.Callable

l << ({ "hello" } as Callable)
```